# Ionic 4: ionic-select is not selected if the model is a number

Tags: ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I have the following code snippet for html and javascript. Notice that the `id` is of type `number`. When the page is loaded, the first option is not selected even if the `model` has the value for the first option.

Note. It works fine if I make the `id` field a `string`.

/** HTML snippet **/

```
 <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Select Color</ion-label>
     <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedId" placeholder="Select">

         <ion-select-option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="color.id">
             {{color.label}}
         </ion-select-option>
     </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

/** Typescript snippet **/

```
 colors = [
     {id: 1, label: 'Red'},
     {id: 2, label: 'Yellow'},
     {id: 3, label: 'Green'}
 ]

 selectedId = colors[0].id;
```

Comment: some here. did you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to see some more of the Typescript code, but essentially in your `.ts` file you would have:

```
selectedId: number;

constructor () {
 this.selectedId = colors[0].id || 1
}
```

In JavaScript, if you prefix a string with a + you get an integer, so in your `html`

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-label>Select Color</ion-label>
     <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedId" placeholder="Select">

         <ion-select-option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="+(color.id)">
             {{color.label}}
         </ion-select-option>
     </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: Does not work for me either and I have hardcoded in my options.

Comment: This worked for me.
This should be on Ionic documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in Ionic 4.  It works if you use strings rather than integers.
Not an ideal fix though.
e.g.

```
 colors = [
     {id: '1', label: 'Red'},
     {id: '2', label: 'Yellow'},
     {id: '3', label: 'Green'}
 ]
```

Comment: still same issue with numbers in 2019 !
did you find a solution better than converting to strings ?

Comment: No, I am haven't tried since I posted this.  This was was only 3 months ago so probably not be resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue using the ionChange event. Try something like this:

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-label>Select Color</ion-label>
     <ion-select (ionChange)="this.selectedId = event.detail.value" placeholder="Select">

         <ion-select-option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="color.id">
             {{color.label}}
         </ion-select-option>
     </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This code sample is working fine. They might fix the issue, right now.
```

html  file

```html
  <ion-select okText="Seç" cancelText="İptal" [(ngModel)]="selectedVersion" [compareWith]="compareWith">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let fv of firmwareVersions" [value]="fv.id">
          {{fv.versionNumber}}
      </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

.ts file

```html
    selectedVersion: any;
    
    firmwareVersions: any[] = [
        {id: 1, versionNumber: 'frjkm3j03jrtm3r3m', description: 'initial version'},
        {id: 2, versionNumber: 'ererefecegfeteg33', description: '2. version'},
        {id: 3, versionNumber: 'fe3r3fhghxh4r2222', description: '3. version'},
        {id: 4, versionNumber: 'tty45yu54y5yy5yu5', description: '4. version'},
    ];
        
    compareWithFn = (o1, o2) => {
        return o1 && o2 ? o1.id === o2.id : o1 === o2;
    }
    
    compareWith = this.compareWithFn;

    constructor() {
        this.selectedVersion = this.firmwareVersions[0].id;
    }
```